# Divergence of Infinite Series: ${e^{(tx)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I need to show whether the following infinite series converges, and if it does, to which value. Here, $t$ is a constant:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{e^{tx}(\frac{1}{2})^{x}}$$
This is my solution:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{e^{tx}(\frac{1}{2})^{x}} = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{e^{t}e^{x}(\frac{1}{2})^{x}} = e^{t}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{(\frac{e}{2})^{x}}$$
$$|\frac{e}{2}| > 1$$
Therefore it diverges.

The solution, however, is that it converges to $\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}$.
What is my mistake here?

Comment: $e^{tx}=\left(e^t\right)^x$, not $e^{t}e^{x}$. Also, note that the series converges iff $t<\ln 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @charlus, ${e^{tx} \neq e^t e^x}$. Instead, you have:

$${=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\left(e^t\right)^{x}0.5^x}$$

$${=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right)^x}$$

This is a geometric series. Provided ${\left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right) < 1}$ (as pointed out by @charlus again, this implies ${t < \ln(2)}$), we have

$${=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right)^{x}-1=\frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}}-1}$$

(I started the index from $0$ and just subtracted $1$ at the end so we can use ${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}}$). Simplifying you get

$${=\frac{2}{2-e^t}-\frac{2-e^t}{2-e^t}=\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}}$$